# Updating geomesa record using Geomesa-Accumulo and Spark with Java API?

Tags: java, update, geomesa

I have found [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/core.html) how to save data using spark and geomesa accumulo. But I can't find anywhere how to update existing records.

I know that Accumulo is under the hood. Accumulo provides data versioning (see this [link](http://accumulodata.com/)). Do I have to use versioning of data? I don't know where to find any geomesa documentation concerning records' update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating records in GeoMesa is expensive since it requires separate deletes and creates.

That can be achieved via the GeoTools DataStore API with the DataStore.getFeatureWriter(filter) method.

GeoMesa's Spark support has evolved from reading data into RDDs to pull data into DataFrames.

After creating a derivative RDD or DataFrame, that entire product can be saved (and in some since could be thought of as a 'new' table in a real sense).  As of November 2019, GeoMesa's integration with Spark doesn't allow for updates directly via the Spark API.